# Numpy read variable amount of columns from a text file into an array

Tags: python, numpy

My file is formatted like this:

```
  2106   2002   27   26   1
 1   0.000000  0.000000 
 2   0.389610  0.000000 
 3   0.779221  0.000000 
 4   1.168831  0.000000 
 5   1.558442  0.000000 
 6   1.948052  0.000000 
 7   2.337662  0.000000 
 8   2.727273  0.000000 
 9   3.116883  0.000000 
 10   3.506494  0.000000
```

I want to read in these. There are more rows than this and some only have two columns. In MATLAB I use readmatrix() and it works well, does Python have anything comparable? Because `python genfromtxt()` and `python loadtxt` do not work with a variable number of columns.

Should I just stick with MATLAB since Python seems to be missing key functionality like this?

Edit: Here is the output that I get in matlab that I would like in numpy:

```
2106    2002    27  26  1   0
1   0   0   0   0   0
2   0.389610000000000   0   0   0   0
3   0.779221000000000   0   0   0   0
4   1.16883100000000    0   0   0   0
5   1.55844200000000    0   0   0   0
6   1.94805200000000    0   0   0   0
7   2.33766200000000    0   0   0   0
8   2.72727300000000    0   0   0   0
9   3.11688300000000    0   0   0   0
10  3.50649400000000    0   0   0   0
```

Comment: have you tried pandas?

Comment: I tried pandas "read_csv" to get a dataframe and then use I data.to_numpy() to convert it to a numpy object. The issue is that I get a bunch of subarrays. Also I am using VS Code and the variable explorer is god awful so I cannot see what it looks like.

Comment: If you don't want subarrays, what format do you want it in?

Comment: In MATLAB I get a single matrix. I use it to fill other arrays and do implicit indexing. I'd really like that I have one matrix/array where can do elements[0:2000,0:4] to get nodal information for an element, for instance.

Comment: @noobquestionsonly it would be nice if you can share the expected output.

Comment: @HozayfaElRifai I edited the question to show the output I'd like.

Comment: @noobquestionsonly dont understand why do you have the zero column. It is not in your text file right?

Comment: It is in reality a 4000x6 array. Later on in the same boundary conditions are specified which give a 6th column.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

headers = []
rows = []
with open("test.txt", 'r') as file:
    for i, v in enumerate(file.readlines()):
        if i == 0:
            headers.extend(v.split())
        else:
            rows.append(v.split())
for i, v in enumerate(rows):
    while len(v) != len(headers):
        v.append(0)
    rows[i] = v
rows = np.array(rows)
```

let me know if any modifications are needed

Comment: I got a memory error. Does Python really lack a simple function to read in an array? It seems much more inefficient than MATLAB

Comment: You only have 4k records, that doesn't make any sense to me, can you share the error ?

Comment: `genfromtxt does read a properly formatted csv.  Your file has missing values which can be handled in various ways .

Answer (score 0):

You have missing values in your columns that matlab interprets them as 0. You can import similar structure to pandas and pandas will have right number of columns. It interprets missing values as `nan` which you can later replace with 0 if you prefer that way. The only catch is have the right column number in first row. If you have 0 at the end of it, put it 0 instead of space:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\s+').fillna(0)
```

output:

```
   2106      2002   27   26    1    0
0     1  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1     2  0.389610  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2     3  0.779221  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3     4  1.168831  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4     5  1.558442  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5     6  1.948052  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6     7  2.337662  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7     8  2.727273  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
8     9  3.116883  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
9    10  3.506494  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: The generated mesh never has a 0 at the end of the header, is there that pandas can automatically tell the max columns? Also when I convert this to a np.array it becomes a collection of subarrays instead of being one big array

Comment: @noobquestionsonly in this solution it does. There could be other ways to deal with it that I am not aware of. Where does the 0 come from? Are there rows with more columns in them that is not present in your sample data or is it extra space at the end of your first line? As for numpy, could you please post what is your desired sample shape so I can help better? Thank you

Comment: you say " If you have 0 at the end of it, put it 0 instead of space," the generated mesh file does not contain the correct amount of columns in the header. My desired shape is 4096x6, one array and not a collection of arrays. I just want one matrix, like you get in MATLAB. Just one cohesive array of my data that is 4096x6.

Comment: I get the error "Exception has occurred: ParserError
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 2108, saw 6" when using "df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\s+').fillna(0)"

Comment: @noobquestionsonly I guess you did not fix the header then. I will post an edit to it accordingly. Looks like you have a row with 6 columns in it but you have only 5 columns in your header which is what I meant by missing column header. Maybe you can have matlab to save all the empty spaces with 0 to resolve this after all.

Comment: @noobquestionsonly what kind of file is your data? would it be possible to upload it here?